# Google sheets Web Scrape script for pricing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape pricing data off of my companies website and im getting an error i cant figure out.

The error im getting is:

> Exception: Error on line 10: Element type "ARRcookies.length" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
> getPrice  @ Price Scraper.gs:11

Here is my code:

```
function getPrice() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange("G2:G" + lastRow);
  var productIds = range.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < productIds.length; i++) {
    var productId = productIds[i][0];
    var url = "https://******.com/products/product&product_id=" + productId;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var html = response.getContentText();
    var doc = XmlService.parse(html);
    var rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
    var xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]";
    var elements = XmlService.getNamespace('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml').getXPathService().evaluate(xpath, rootNode);
    var price = elements[0].getValue();
    sheet.getRange(i + 2, 14).setValue(price);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
}
```

Im not really sure what the error means and when i google it, i cant find anything.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Others may have more specific skills with this, but you should edit your question to provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) . How else can one try to reproduce the results of your script?

Comment: What are you talking about?

I supplied the code I'm using, as well as the Error I'm receiving.What else do you need?